# Is there any built in way to detect internet not connected in okhttp.?

Tags: android, okhttp

Is there any built in way to detect internet not connected in okhttp. I have made my own implementation for this particular thing but just wanted to know if something related to this is already included in the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With okhttp 2.5.0 if there is no internet connection then the control would fall in onFailure() function of the okhttp callback class. There you can check the cause from the exception and do what you need to.
P.S use enqueue method for request execution.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way I have found is

if(!response.isSuccessful())

This doesn't give me status codes but it gets the job done!